# Is it possible to declare a GDB convenience variable as an array?

Tags: gdb

I would like to declare an array convenience variable, such as

```
set $list[10]
```

but I get a syntax error.

Is it possible to create a vector using convenience variables?

I could use pointers, if I can find an absolute area memory GDB can use that the target program won't use.

Oh, BTW, I don't have a symbol table for the target program I am debugging, using a compiler not compatible with GDB.

The cross-target version of GDB I have does not support python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is only possible if you allocate memory in the inferior.  That is, try something like:

```
set $list = (int *) malloc (10 * sizeof (int))
```

Change the types to suit.

Another similar option is to use the {...} feature.  I am not sure offhand, but I think this may allocate memory in the inferior in some cases.  Anyway, try:

```
print {1,2,3,4}[2]
```

I get

```
$1 = 3
```

Comment: I'll try the {...} feature. I can't use malloc() as I don't have a symbol table thus gdb doesn't know where malloc() is. I could create a convenience variable, $Malloc with the address of malloc from the map. That might work.

Comment: If you have any usable address you can use the {TYPE} cast to treat it like something else.  For example:  set $var = {int[4]} &main.  Or something like that, see the manual -- I have trouble remembering the exact syntax of this extension.

Comment: @TomTromey I don't think it is only possible via manual allocating a memory in the inferrior. Look: the code `set $test="Hello"`,`p perror($test)` works fine. You can even take the address of.

Comment: I think that snippet will result in gdb calling malloc in the inferior to make some space for the string.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

For example,

```
(gdb) set $a = (int [3]) {0}
(gdb) p $a
$14 = {0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Where is such an array allocated when e.g. remote debugging an embedded device?